# How to file federal and state (MA) taxes following legal name change?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

I legally changed my name by becoming a U.S. citizen, but because all this happened recently (4/13), I am not sure how to file taxes by the 18th. I know I have to alert the SSA of the name change (I've downloaded the form), but should I also file for a tax filing extension?

Second, how do I pay taxes by the 18th if I am doing all this through something like TurboTax?

Third, how do I file for a tax filing extension for the state of MA? I found [this](http://www.mass.gov/dor/individuals/filing-and-payment-information/filing-options/automatic-extensions-on-the-web.html) online, correct me if I am wrong but basically I pay 80% and automatically have an extension?

I am confused because I use something like Turbotax to determine how much I owe. **Should I just fill out the Turboxtax application to determine the owe amounts, pay those by the 18th, and file for an extension so the SSA has time to catch up to my name change?**

What is the best way to approach this situation?

Comment: generally as long as you have updated with the SSA, you will be fine, just file under your new name on the main form, but for the W2 section, make sure you report it EXACTLY as it is named, you will be fine, I know 3 people who went through this and were just fine and nothing ever became an issue BUT it is important that your SSA is CORRECT, generally if you have your new SSN card, you are done. IF, and a big if, an issue arises, it will be administratively remedied with a simple followup. Consult a tax attorney to be certain in case something has changed in the last 4 years. Doubtful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File based on what your name *is*.   Because IRS requires you give truthful information.  Don't give them stale info because you are concerned about a sync problem.

If you think you might owe money, **pay on time** at least as much as you will owe (it's ok to pay too much, you'll get it back when you file).  Your payment needs to go with a form, and you can use a Form 4868 as that form.   You'd have to check what MA wants, probably something similar.

If you want to fool around with some sort of e-pay, have fun, but if something goes wrong with that, you will be liable.   By contrast, *paper is real*.  If you send it in by mail on paper, IRS cannot ignore it or claim they had a problem processing it.

Once you have prepaid more than your taxes actually will be, then you can take your time and file.   There is no penalty for filing late if the IRS owes you money.  The Form 4868 gives you a statutory right to file late, but it does not provide an extension to *pay*, so the same interest and penalties would apply.

It's rather unlikely that IRS will look seriously at your form within 3 months, it often takes them a year to notice problems in tax forms.  And whatever you're doing, they see this all the time... so if they see a name change, they'll go "I bet that's a legal name change, we'll just confirm that with other data".   It's in IRS's interest to give stuff like this time to auto-resolve, rather than have their agents waste time.

A tax return which is filed on paper is a legal document you signed, the IRS has to take it, they can't bounce it back on a technicality and claim you didn't file, as they can on the e-file systems.  And if they don't like something you said, they have to follow up (and they will, shockingly slowly).